# emacs ABBRV command break for new line

Tags: abbrev

i want to add an abbrv for 2 lines (that is a 1st line, a break and then a 2nd line)
Anyone know the syntax for that?
here is the syntax i try

`("8rt" "#+ATTR_HTML: :style color:green  *lets try it on your computer!*" nil 0)`

i want the breakline to come right after the `:green`

any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert `"\n"` where you want the newline. This works for me:

```
("8rt" "#+ATTR_HTML: :style color:green\n  *lets try it on your computer!*")
```

I don't think the `nil` and `0` are necessary.